# How to use setCACert() of WiFiClientSecure with HTTPClient library?

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'd like to set my CA root cert (currently available via [WiFiClientSecure](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/WiFiClientSecure.cpp) library) and use convenient [HTTPClient](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient) library for making request.

How to do that? In [the example](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/HTTPSRequestCACert/HTTPSRequestCACert.ino) there is only showed how to use [WiFiClientSecure](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/WiFiClientSecure.cpp) with manually written request.

Comment: The library only supports the `HTTPClient::begin(String host, uint16_t port, String uri, String httpsFingerprint)`, i.e. the fingerprint. If you want to verify by the root certificate, you have to hack into the library yourself, for example with the functions you showed. **edit**: Or just clone the repo again and pull in pull-reqest https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/pull/3176 .

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Sad thing is, that the master branch of the newest version of the repo doesn't have setRootCA() method in HTTPClient. It has setCACert() method in WiFiClientSecure instead. I thought there's a reason why we don't have setRootCA() and have setCACert() instead. Isn't there?

Comment: Oh, now I see that it's just waiting for approval.

Answer (score 0):

It's way to late but this post is one one of the ones that gets returned by google so it's a good way to help others like me who are just starting out with this.

It turns out that all the posts about WifiClientSecure are obsolete (or simply unnecessary).

Here's a working example using the default HTTPClient. (not HttpClient)
It does require setting the certificate's sha1 fingerprint in the begin statement.

```
void loop() {
  // wait for WiFi connection
  if ((WiFiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED)) {

    HTTPClient http;

    Serial.print("[HTTPS] begin...\n");

    http.begin("https://some.secure_server.com/auth/authorise", "2F 2A BB 23 6B 03 89 76 E6 4C B8 36 E4 A6 BF 84 3D DA D3 9F");

    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    int httpCode = http.POST("user_id=mylogin&user_password=this%20is%20my%20%24ecret%20pa%24%24word");
    if (httpCode > 0) {
      http.writeToStream(&Serial);

      // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
      Serial.printf("[HTTP] ... code: %d\n", httpCode);

      // file found at server
      if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
        String payload = http.getString();
        Serial.println(payload);
      }
    } else {
      Serial.printf("[HTTP] ... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
    }
    http.end();
  }

  delay(10000);
}
```